# Mocking HttpResponse WriteAsync

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq, xunit

I'm trying to get a call to `WriteAsync` mocked on a mock`HttpResponse` and I can't figure out the syntax to use.

```
var responseMock = new Mock<HttpResponse>();
responseMock.Setup(x => x.WriteAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()));

ctx.Setup(x => x.Response).Returns(responseMock.Object);
```

The test bombs with the following error:

> System.NotSupportedException : Invalid setup on an extension method: x
>   => x.WriteAsync(It.IsAny(), It.IsAny())

Ultimately I want to verify the correct string has been written to the response.

How to correctly set this up?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Moq cannot `Setup` extension methods. If you know what the extension method accesses then some cases you can mock a safe path through the extension method.

[WriteAsync(HttpResponse, String, CancellationToken)](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions/Extensions/HttpResponseWritingExtensions.cs)

> Writes the given text to the response body. UTF-8 encoding will be used.

directly accesses the `HttpResponse.Body.WriteAsync` where `Body` is a `Stream` via the following overload

```
/// <summary>
/// Writes the given text to the response body using the given encoding.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="response">The <see cref="HttpResponse"/>.</param>
/// <param name="text">The text to write to the response.</param>
/// <param name="encoding">The encoding to use.</param>
/// <param name="cancellationToken">Notifies when request operations should be cancelled.</param>
/// <returns>A task that represents the completion of the write operation.</returns>
public static Task WriteAsync(this HttpResponse response, string text, Encoding encoding, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    if (response == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(response));
    }

    if (text == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(text));
    }

    if (encoding == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(encoding));
    }

    byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(text);
    return response.Body.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length, cancellationToken);
}
```

This means you would need mock `response.Body.WriteAsync`

```
//Arrange
var expected = "Hello World";
string actual = null;
var responseMock = new Mock<HttpResponse>();
responseMock
    .Setup(_ => _.Body.WriteAsync(It.IsAny<byte[]>(),It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
    .Callback((byte[] data, int offset, int length, CancellationToken token)=> {
        if(length > 0)
            actual = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
    })
    .ReturnsAsync();

//...code removed for brevity

//...
Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
```

The callback was used to capture the arguments passed to the mocked member. Its value was stored in a variable to be asserted later in the test.

Comment: This was a great answer but unfortunately doesn't work with .NET Core 3.1 - the extension methods became a lot more complicated. I would appreciate any guidance... thanks.

Comment: @StevenDarby I'll have to go take a look at the new version to figure out what changed. Do you have a link to the new source, to save me hunting it down?

Comment: @StevenDarby Ok found the new source. Checking it out.

Comment: @StevenDarby Yes things have become way more complicated in more recent version. Try using a `DefaultHttpContext` instead and modifying its response to suit your test case.

Comment: Thank you - that's what I did in the end. Found I didn't need a mock in this particular case. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Usage of DefaultHttpContext with .NET Core 3.1 worked for me as well. The only thing is setup of Response.Body with MemoryStream (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45959605/inspect-defaulthttpcontext-body-in-unit-test-situation), since I have assertion of body content in my unit tests

Answer (score 11):

Here's a solution that seems to work in .NET Core 3.1, for completeness:

```
const string expectedResponseText = "I see your schwartz is as big as mine!";

DefaultHttpContext httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
httpContext.Response.Body = new MemoryStream();

// Whatever your test needs to do

httpContext.Response.Body.Position = 0;
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(httpContext.Response.Body))
{
    string actualResponseText = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
    Assert.Equal(expectedResponseText, actualResponseText);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With .Net 6 it was such a pain I ended up using a real implementation.

```
    // It's a PAIN to unit test Response.WriteAsync, just use a Real HttpContext 
    //_httpContextMock.Setup(x => x.Request.Path).Returns(new PathString("/api/test"));
    //_httpContextMock.Setup(x => x.Connection.Id).Returns("1");
    //_httpContextMock.Setup(x => x.Request.Headers).Returns(new HeaderDictionary() { { RequestLoggingMiddleware.TraceIdHeaderName, new[] { invalidTraceId } } });
    //_httpContextMock.Setup(x => x.Response.Body).Returns(new MemoryStream());  //<- PAIN TO TEST
    //_httpContextMock.SetupProperty(x => x.Response.ContentType);
    //_httpContextMock.SetupProperty(x => x.Response.StatusCode);
    //_requestDelegateMock.Setup(x => x(_httpContextMock.Object)).Returns(Task.CompletedTask);

    var context = new DefaultHttpContext();
    context.Response.Body = new MemoryStream();
    context.Request.Headers.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, StringValues>(traceIdHeaderName, invalidTraceId));
    
    // Act
    await _middleware.InvokeAsync(context, _loggingContextMock.Object);
```