# Initializing DefaultHttpContext.Response.Body to MemoryStream throws NullReferencePointer

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, middleware, httpcontext, exceptionhandler

I am working on implementation of global exception middleware and I would like to cover middleware with unit tests. Below you see how far I got.

This is a code of unit test.

```cs
    [Fact]
    public async Task MethodName_StateUnderTest_ExpectedBehavior()
    {
        //Arrange
        IExceptionHandlerFeature exceptionHandlerFeature = new ExceptionHandlerFeature {Error = new NotFoundException()};

        IFeatureCollection features = new FeatureCollection();
        features.Set(exceptionHandlerFeature);

        var context = new DefaultHttpContext(features);
        context.Response.Body = new MemoryStream();
        //Act
        await ExceptionMiddleware.HandleException(context);

        //Assert
        context.Response.StatusCode.Should().Be((int) HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }
```

This is a code of ExceptionMiddleware.Handle method

```cs
public static async Task HandleException(HttpContext context)
{
    var contextFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();

    if (contextFeature == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (contextFeature.Error is AppValidationException validationException)
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;

        var failures = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(validationException.Failures);

        await context.Response.WriteAsync(
            new ErrorDetails
            {
                StatusCode = context.Response.StatusCode,
                Message = contextFeature.Error.Message,
                StackTrace = contextFeature.Error.StackTrace,
                Detail = failures
            }.ToString());

        return;
    }

    context.Response.StatusCode = (int) ResolveStatusCodeFromExceptionType(contextFeature.Error);
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

    await context.Response.WriteAsync(
        new ErrorDetails
        {
            StatusCode = context.Response.StatusCode,
            Message = contextFeature.Error.Message,
            StackTrace = contextFeature.Error.StackTrace
        }.ToString());
}
```

Test is crushing on line

```cs
context.Response.Body = new MemoryStream();
```

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45959605/inspect-defaulthttpcontext-body-in-unit-test-situation), everything should be fine but I still can't initialize property Body.

Test Projects target framework is .Net Core 3.0.
*ExceptionMiddleware.cs* is in project with set target framework .NET Standard 2.1 and it is Class Library.

StackTrace of exception is really short:

> at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.DefaultHttpResponse.set_Body(Stream
>   value)    at
>   Itixis.Shared.API.Tests.ExceptionMiddlewareTests.d__0.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\Users\daniel.rusnok\source\repos\Itixis\Itixis.Shared\Tests\Itixis.Shared.API.Tests\ExceptionMiddlewareTests.cs:line
>   35

Comment: Have you stepped through the code while debugging?

Comment: Also try it without setting any features and see what happens

Comment: Aaaaa.. okey.. there is a bug.. features are making it. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By manually setting the features you are removing the ones set by default, which causes your null error.

```cs
    public DefaultHttpContext()
        : this(new FeatureCollection())
    {
        Features.Set<IHttpRequestFeature>(new HttpRequestFeature());
        Features.Set<IHttpResponseFeature>(new HttpResponseFeature());
        Features.Set<IHttpResponseBodyFeature>(new StreamResponseBodyFeature(Stream.Null));
    }

    public DefaultHttpContext(IFeatureCollection features)
    {
        _features.Initalize(features);
        _request = new DefaultHttpRequest(this);
        _response = new DefaultHttpResponse(this);
    }
```

[Source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Http/Http/src/DefaultHttpContext.cs#L35)

Note the request, response and response body features added in the default constructor.

Either try recreating what was done in the default constructor by also adding the required features,

```cs
IExceptionHandlerFeature exceptionHandlerFeature = new ExceptionHandlerFeature {Error = new NotFoundException()};

IFeatureCollection features = new FeatureCollection();
features.Set(exceptionHandlerFeature);
features.Set<IHttpRequestFeature>(new HttpRequestFeature());
features.Set<IHttpResponseFeature>(new HttpResponseFeature());
features.Set<IHttpResponseBodyFeature>(new StreamResponseBodyFeature(Stream.Null));

var context = new DefaultHttpContext(features);

//...
```

or remove the manual feature and use the default constructor.

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task MethodName_StateUnderTest_ExpectedBehavior() {
    //Arrange
    var context = new DefaultHttpContext();
    context.Response.Body = new MemoryStream();
    //Act
    await ExceptionMiddleware.HandleException(context);

    //Assert
    context.Response.StatusCode.Should().Be((int) HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
}
```

and it should work as expected.